# MVC default model binder returns Null object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having an issue where the default model binder is refusing to bind to my object, which is a `List<>` of simple objects.

The class:

```
public class ReferralHistoryDetail {

    [Key]
    public long Referral_Number { get; set; }
    public Guid QuoteGuid { get; set; }
    public byte ReferralTypeID { get; set; }
    public string Referral_Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReferralDateTime { get; set; }
    public string ReferralComments { get; set; }

}
```

The controller definition:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(List<ReferralHistoryDetail> details) {
```

The view from Fiddler:

[image: The view from Fiddler]

What am I doing wrong here?

This is shown via an EditorTemplate in the following manner:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Home")) {

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active form-horizontal" id="basic">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ReferralHistoryDetail)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

The value that is coming across as NULL is the one being passed to the POST method of the controller.  The default model binder is not able to bind this.

Comment: More than likely its because the HistoryDetail doesn't match the class name ReferralHistoryDetail.

Comment: You dont need to have either HistoryDetail or ReferralHistoryDetail.  Just `name="[0].ReferralTypeID"` etc will do

Comment: I'm using an EditorTemplate for this model and just displaying it via EditorFor<>().  MVC is controlling the rest.

Comment: What is your `@model` definition in the view?

Comment: @model ReferralHistoryDetail ... this is being shown in an editor template from a  parent view who's model this List<> as a property called HistoryDetail which I think may be the issue here? Is it not mapping due to the class name difference?  The HTML form doesn't involve the parent it just involves this child list.

Comment: @Coulton See my response above.  I have also edited my post to show how this is being setup from the parent view.

Comment: The server side action is expecting a list<ReferralHistoryDetail> but `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.HistoryDetail)` refers to just 1 object. am I missing something? btw as far as I know there is no generic editorfor for enumerable objects...

Comment: The EditorFor actually returns multiple objects, all named correctly, due to the fact it is being passed a List<> and not a single object.  Names such as HistoryDetail_0__ReferralComments, HistoryDetail_1__ReferralComments, etc.

Comment: hmm, not sure that I understand your problem then. what are you getting as null?

Comment: The value in the controller's POST action is NULL.  I have edited my post to show my new code, which has the actual values matching the class name, so that's not the issue.  I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: How does your editor template looks like ?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this.

The problem is the `Html.BeginForm()` is in the main view, but it is only posting back stuff from the `EditorFor()`'s.

I had to change my controller to take in the main view's object and not the object that the `EditorFor()` is dealing with, because the `Html.BeginForm()` lives on the main view.